# How to redirect to a dynamic URL with apache mode_rewrite rules (not the classic redirection)?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I want to use apache mod_rewrite rules to redirect to a dynamic URL, without changing the URL itself.

> **the dynamic URL** : *www.example.com/business/carwash*

in above url, the 'carwash' part is a username that is passed to find the specific business.
I want a URL like this : ***carwash.example.com***
to be redirected to show the content of this URL : ***www.example.com/business/carwash***
without changing the URL (the URL remains *carwash.example.com* ).

I tryed the following code :

## RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^carwash.cityrakhsh.com

## RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/business/carwash [P]

but it didn't work.
How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

subdomain, in this case **carwash**, can be substituted in the rewrite rule using %1

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).cityrakhsh.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) "http://cityrakhsh.com/business/%1/" [P]
```